# Why Tooling API doesn't support composite/sobjects resource?

Tags: rest-api, tooling-api, restresource

[The documentation for Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_resources_composite_sobjects_collections_update.htm) suggests that Tooling API supports composite/sobjects resource

> Update Multiple Records with Fewer Round-Trips Use a PATCH request
> with sObject Collections to update multiple records, returning a list
> of SaveResult objects. You can choose whether to roll back the entire
> request when an error occurs.

However, looks like in fact, this resource is not supported, since any PATCH calls to this resource return

```
Service not found at: /services/data/v56.0/tooling/composite/sobjects
```

error.

Also, the link to the API resource in documentation is also wrong:

```
PATCH /vXX.X/composite/sobjects
```

while in fact, for tooling api, it is `/v56.0tooling/composite/sobjects`.

If usual REST API resource is used, another error is returned "SObject is not supported".

Is there are workaround other than using Metadata API to bulk update custom fields, custom objects and other Tooling API objects?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in API and also a documentation bug in Salesforce documentation.

However, I am really tired to open Salesforce Support cases to report about such Salesforce bugs to Salesforce Support.

Comment: For doc bugs, no need to open a case directly. The "Share Your Feedback" button opens a form that takes like a minute to fill out, and you're done. The doc team has been really good about reading bug reports and getting it fixed. Also, they have a twitter (search Salesforce Docs), they'll be happy to respond pretty quickly.